# How to Increase Java Heap Size in AWS ECS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have REST API developed in Java SpringBoot. I have deployed this API as a docker container in AWS ECS. I have allocated 2048 MB as hard memory and 1024 as soft memory in the AWS Task. After ECS launches the docker container, I access the docker container and executed the following command

> java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize

I get the following result

```
 uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                   {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 33554432                            {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    **uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 536870912**                           {product}
```

The MaxHeapSize shown in the result is 536870912 which is approx 536 MB (around half of the soft memory)

I would like to know how can I increase this heap size to at least 800 MB in the AWS ECS environment.

I know how to set the heap size using the command java -Xmx800m, but I do not know where to execute this command in the AWS ECS enviornment.

Comment: If you are using Java 11, you should not set this setting. There are new settings for containers that use a percentage of the total memory for heap. IIRC it defaults to 80%.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/xxinitialrampercentage/

Answer (score 4):

For me, it worked by setting the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` in my ECS Task Definition like this:

| Environment Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS | -XX:InitialHeapSize=1g -XX:MaxHeapSize=2g |

I hope this helps!

BTW, my container was running with Amazon Corretto JDK version 8.

Comment: works well, Java will recognize JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in the env without any additional changes

Answer (score 2):

Add xmx property in your dockerfile. eg cmd java -Xmx800m your_jar

Comment: I tried CMD ["java", "-Xmx3024m", "-Xms3024m", "-jar",  "-Dconfpath=/conf",  "-Dspring.profiles.active=aws", "/opt/lib/myjar.jar"]  but this gave me error "Error: Could not find or load main class java".   So, I used the command CMD ["-Xmx3024m", "-Xms3024m", "-jar",  "-Dconfpath=/conf",  "-Dspring.profiles.active=aws", "/opt/lib/myjar.jar"] which worked,but the heap size is not changed to 3 GB. The heap size is always shown as 756 MB. any idea?

Comment: Try this ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java -Xmx3024m -Xms3024m -jar urjar"]
CMD [--spring.profiles.active=prod]

Comment: Also if you can ssh in container and process command ie how what command is actually running. Check the memory given to container.   You should also check the memory limits specified in task definition in aws ecs

Answer (score 2):

For me the -Xmx seemed not to be ignored by ECS.

I increased the Task vCPU and memory parameters, and wanted the heap size to be increased.

I used the parameter `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0` in the override of the container Command. It finally worked.

Comment: How were you able to log into ECS to see if the options were ignored or not? @Erwan

Comment: I logged the `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`, `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`, and `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`. I don't think we can log into ECS instance, so I made the info come to me :) and compared with what I configured.